# If $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N} c_n=S<\infty$, and $b_n=\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$, can I conclude that $b_n$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis

I am studying series again. Analyzing an exercise, a doubt arose:

Let $(c_n)$ a sequence of positive numbers such that
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb N} c_n=S<\infty.$$

If $b_n=\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$. Can I conclude that $b_n$ converges?

If the sequence $(b_n)$ does not converges, I am looking for an example of that.

Comment: @πr8 That is not a sequence of *positive* numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Try with

$$\;c_n:=\begin{cases}\frac1{n^2}\,,&n\;\text{is odd}\\{}\\\frac3{n^2},\,&n\;\text{is even}\end{cases}\;$$

Answer (score 2):

Try examples of the form
$$ c_n = \cases{ u_n & if $n$ is even\cr
                 v_n & if $n$ is odd\cr}$$
where $\sum_n u_n < \infty$ and $\sum_n v_n < \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**:I would say no. Define $c_n = \dfrac{1}{n^2}$ if $n$ is odd, and $\dfrac{1}{n^3}$ if $n$ is even.